# Bug in windows bluetooth le GetGattServicesAsync method

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, c#

**The problem description:** 
Sometimes it is not possible to get some response from the method `GetGattServicesAsync` with the parameter `BluetoothCacheMode.Cached` or `BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached`. Only the windows restart helps to reconnect the le device and to get the services from the le device.

We use `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll` with .Net Framework 4.6.1 to build the class library.
The Windows PC shall connect the Bluetooth le device.

**Steps for the problem reproducing:**

1. Discovery the devices with the determined service
2. Call the method FromBluetoothAddressAsync with the Bluetooth address of LE device
3. BluetoothLEDevice is found
4. Pair the LE device with desktop:

   ```
   DeviceInformationPairing loPairingInf = poDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing;
   if (!loPairingInf.IsPaired)
   {
       DevicePairingKinds loConfirm = DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly;
       DevicePairingProtectionLevel loProtectionLevel = DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Default;
       DeviceInformationCustomPairing loCustomPairing = loPairingInf.Custom;
   ```
5. Check the connection status. If the status connected, call the method `GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached)`
6. Sometimes is not possible to get the response from `GetGattServicesAsync`. After 30 seconds we cancel the task, dispone BluetoothLEDevice, unpair and try to reconnect le device. The reconnection is failed and only the Windows restart helps to establish the connection to the le device.

**PC:**

- Dell Precision 5530
- Bluetooth adapter Qualcomm QCA6174A
- Windows 10 Enterprise (1803)
- Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134.590

**LE Device:**

- Bluetooth 4.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this as [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) because this is a programming question. It would be better fit on [so], but there's no actual question here, just a bug report.

Comment: Do not pair with BLE device. THer eis a bug that you can not read information from device if it is paired. More details ablout Win version and possible BLE issues: https://www.btframework.com/ble.htm

Comment: @Yury did you ever get an answer somewhere to this?